# WC Срок действия купонов

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Как вывести дату окончания действия купона?

Вот мой код, я тут уже вывел название и короткое описание купона, а как дату окончания действия вывести (Expiry date) ?

```
$couponargs = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
    'post__in' => $couponarrayfinal,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1'); 
$coupons = get_posts($couponargs);

<div class="wt-mycoupons">
   <ul>
    <?php
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        // if( $coupon->post_title == 'test-coupons' ) {

        // } else {

        // }

        echo "<li class='wt-single-coupon'><div class='title-coupon'>$coupon->post_title</div><div class='desc-coupon'>$coupon->post_excerpt</div></li>";
    }
    ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_posts()` возвращает посты типа купон. Вам нужно получить объект купон и вывести его дату окончания с помощью метода объекта:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1);
$coupon_posts = get_posts($args);

foreach ( $coupon_posts as $coupon_post ) {
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_post->ID );
    $expires = $coupon->get_date_expires();
    if ( $expires ) {
        echo ->format( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Написал как у вас, в итоге выводит вот это: ()->format( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' );

Comment: В чем можеть быть моя ошибка? Вот скрин кода: http://prntscr.com/m8wa4g Такое ощущение что php что-то тут не нравиться где я позначил.

Comment: А если пропишу в точ точ как у вас то ложится сайт: http://prntscr.com/m8wbk2

Comment: Разобрался в чем проблема, дату вывело и сайт не ложиться если удалить строчку format();

Comment: Но формат плохой( http://prntscr.com/m8wjzx

Comment: У вас, похоже пробел после `get_date_expires()`. Скопируйте мой код через ctrl+c, ctrl+v

Comment: Пробела нету, вот: http://prntscr.com/m8x37v, а сайт всеравно сыпется. Может у меня плохая версия php?

Comment: Поправил ответ.